# Packets getting corrupted with netty

Tags: java, networking, netty, voip, packet

I'm making a secure VOIP program in java, and I chose to use netty to simply my networking. So far it's actually been the biggest cost of time for the project.. The VOIP works fine on localhost, but when I go to another computer on the network, something strange happens. Right now there are only two packets, 50 for chat and 51 for a voice sample. The program runs fine for a few frames, then I receive random packet numbers, and invalid sizes. I'm not sure what is causing this..

Here is the class that transmits the packets:

```
package com.io;

import com.gui.VoiceCallFrame;
import com.net.Session;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBufAllocator;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

/**
 * @author Colby
 */
public class VoiceTransmitHandler implements VoiceIOHandler {

    public VoiceTransmitHandler(String name,  Session remote) {
        this.remote = remote;

        VoiceCallFrame frame = new VoiceCallFrame(name, this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private Session remote;
    private boolean running;

    public void start() {
        running = true;

        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(16000.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
                    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

                    TargetDataLine microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    try {
                        microphone.open(format);
                        microphone.start();

                        byte[] buf = new byte[4000];
                        do {
                            int len = microphone.read(buf, 0, buf.length);

                            ByteBuf packet = ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.buffer();
                            packet.writeByte(51);
                            packet.writeShort(len);
                            packet.writeBytes(buf, 0, len);
                            System.out.println("Send: " + packet.readableBytes());
                            remote.writeTCP(packet);

                        } while (running);

                    } finally {
                        microphone.close();
                    }
                } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                    running = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Here is where the packets are decoded:

```
@Override
public void readTCP(ByteBuf msg) {
    if (opcode == -1) {
        if (msg.readableBytes() < 3) {
            return;
        }
        opcode = msg.readUnsignedByte();
        length = msg.readUnsignedShort();
    }

    if (msg.readableBytes() < length) {
        return;
    }

    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    msg.readBytes(data);
    try {
        System.out.println("Packet received " + opcode + ":" + length);

        switch(opcode) {

            case 51://Voice received
                if(vrh == null) {
                    vrh = new VoiceReceiveHandler(host.getHostAddress());
                    vrh.start();
                }
                vrh.playLater(data);
                break;
        }

    } finally {
        opcode = length = -1;
    }
}
```

Where that is called from in my ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    session.readTCP((ByteBuf) msg);
}
```

I don't see where my packets could be getting messed up at all. It looks to me as I am transmitting and decoding them correctly. If there is any more relevant code needed just leave a message.

Comment: Does `msg.readBytes` always fill the whole array, or does it return a variable number of bytes like `InputStream.read` does?

Comment: It would appear to fill the whole array:
"public abstract ByteBuf readBytes(byte[] dst)
Transfers this buffer's data to the specified destination starting at the current readerIndex and increases the readerIndex by the number of the transferred bytes (= dst.length).
Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if dst.length is greater than this.readableBytes"

Comment: Just to add, here is the output:
Packet received 51:4000
Packet received 51:4000
Packet received 51:4000
Packet received 64:576

Comment: You appear to be writing default bytes and shorts (which will be signed) but reading unsigned bytes. Have you tried with these aligned, so the read and write are the same?

Comment: @Mick In java there is no special method to read signed values. Correct me if I;m wrong

Comment: Hi @Colby - Bytebuf has a readByte() and a readUnsignedByte() method (you are using the latter) - given that you write the opcode as a 'normal' byte, you may want to read it that way also?

Comment: What does your Netty pipeline look like? I'd hazard a guess that you're seeing fragmentation caused by TCP (see Dealing with a Stream-based Transport in the docs http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-11). You might only need a LengtFieldBasedFrameDecoder to ensure you receive packets intact. http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend check errors on your (nic) network interface :

```
# netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface       MTU Met    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500   0 199549124      0      0      0 153882468      0      0      0 BMRU
eth1       1500   0 138357627      0    630      0 151312724      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        16436   0        0      0      0      0        0      0      0      0 LRU
```

Or else download and install the following tool to check the status
 http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/nicstat/nicstat-1.92.tar.gz